# Как верно построить структуру БД спарсенных просмотров и вывести из неё данные в сводную таблицу HTML?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Уважаемые эксперты.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, логику действий по добавлению и выводу спарсенных данных:

С помощью PHP Simple Html Dom Parser парсятся названия и количество просмотров каждой статьи с [данной страницы](http://baltluch.ru/ecotropa47) и заносятся в БД.

```php
include ('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://baltluch.ru/ecotropa47');

foreach ($html->find('div.publication') as $pub)
{

    $title = $pub->find('h3.publ_title', 0);

    $stat = $pub->find('.pink_numbers', 0);

    echo "<tr><td>$title->plaintext</td><td>$stat</td></tr>";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    if (!$conn)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $today = date("d.m.y");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO bluch_views (bluch_date, bluch_title, bluch_views) VALUES ('{$today}', '{$title->plaintext}', '{$stat}')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);

}
```

После занесения в БД, таблица выглядит так:

```
| bluch_date | bluch_title    | bluch_views |
| 08.12.2019 |название_статьи |     25      |
| 08.12.2019 |название_статьи2|     32      |
| 08.12.2019 |название_статьи3|     32      |
```

После обновления файла, например, на следующий день, в базу добавляются новые данные и таблица выглядит следующим образом:

```
| bluch_date | bluch_title    | bluch_views |
| 08.12.2019 |название_статьи |     25      |
| 08.12.2019 |название_статьи2|     32      |
| 08.12.2019 |название_статьи3|     32      |
| 09.12.2019 |название_статьи |     30      |
| 09.12.2019 |название_статьи2|     40      |
| 09.12.2019 |название_статьи3|     50      |
```

Выводя данные из таблицы в отдельный файл:

```php
$sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `bluch_title` FROM `bluch_views`');
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "<tr><td>{$result['bluch_title']}</td><td>{$result['bluch_views']}</td></tr>";
}
```

Получаю таблицу такого вида в HTML:

```
|    Дата    |   ИМЯ СТАТЬИ   |  Просмотры  |
| 08.12.2019 |название_статьи |     25      |
| 08.12.2019 |название_статьи2|     32      |
| 08.12.2019 |название_статьи3|     32      |
| 09.12.2019 |название_статьи |     30      |
| 09.12.2019 |название_статьи2|     40      |
| 09.12.2019 |название_статьи3|     50      |
```

Вопрос: Какую создать структуру БД, чтобы реализовать вывод в отдельный файл HTML-таблицы такого вида:

```
|   ИМЯ СТАТЬИ   |  08.12.2019 | 09.12.2019 | 10.12.2019 | 11.12.2019 |
|название_статьи |     25      |     30     |     35     |     44     |
|название_статьи2|     32      |     40     |     48     |     52     |
|название_статьи3|     32      |     38     |     52     |     63     |
```

То есть после каждодневного обновления файла, в БД заносятся данные о просмотре каждой статьи, а затем в отдельном файле в таблице добавляется столбец с данными о просмотрах за каждый день.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Структура - нормальная. А сводную таблицу стройте на клиенте, его средствами - ибо pivot средствами MySQL есть штука непростая.

Comment: костыль но сделал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я потренировался на своей таблице https://ibb.co/h269716
[таблица](https://ibb.co/h269716)

и вот мой код

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', '**', '', 'test');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$query = "select * from table01 ";
$result = $conn->query($query);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$arr2[]=$row2;
}

$row=count($arr2);
for($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++) {

$dat[$arr2[$i]['date1']]=1; //делаем уникальную дату(ключь не может повторятся)
$name[$arr2[$i]['bluch_title']]=2;//делаем уникальное название(ключь не может повторятся)
}

echo '<table border="1">';

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>Name';
foreach ($dat as $key => $value) {
    echo'<td>'.$key;
}
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';


foreach ($name as $key1 => $value1) {


foreach ($dat as $key => $value) {
$query0 = "select * from table01 where date1='".$key."' and bluch_title='".$key1."'";
$result2 = $conn->query($query0);
while($row21 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
$arr21[]=$row21['bluch_views'];
}
}}
$res=array_chunk($arr21, 2, TRUE); //разбиваем массив
foreach ($res as $key6 => $value6) {
    # code...
    $fud[]=array_values($value6); //пересоздаём ключи во вложенном массиве
}

$k='-1';

foreach ($name as $key1 => $value1) {
$k++;
echo'<tr><td>'.$key1.'<td>'.$fud[$k][0].'<td>'.$fud[$k][1].'</td>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

вот результат https://ibb.co/8xXszyn

Comment: Работает безупречно. Спасибо за столь подробное решение!

Comment: Обращайтесь _).

Comment: Жаль, что только не работает динамически: при добавлении новых данных - не генерируется новый столбец и массив разбивается также на 2 части вместо 3-х, а затем уже 4-х ,5-и и так далее) Подскажите, пожалуйста, на что обратить внимание для такой реализации?

Comment: Посмотрю по позже на счёт динамики

Comment: Вот так попробуй https://pastebin.com/Fv1WyuC2

Comment: Да, почти идеально! Сегодня добавилась новая статья, и её просмотры добавляются в  самую первую колонку, на первую дату, а не последнюю) Но с этим уже разберусь сам) Благодарю, что уделили столько времени и сил, придя мне на помощь)

Comment: смысл понятен должен быть, можно допилить